# Keep the value of data in form during insert into database using PHP, JQUERY

Tags: php, cakephp, jquery

I have the code as below:

```
<form method="post" name ="frm">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type ="text" id="name"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Sex:</td>
    <td>Female<input type ="radio" id="female" name="female"> </td>
    <td>Male<input type ="radio" id="male" name="male"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type ="submit" id="btnSave" name="btnSave"></td>

</tr>
</table>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["btnSave"])){

    //insert it to data base.........
    // the problem is that during insert it to database ,the data will store in database but the form of Name value,Sex value,it displays empty
    //I do not want like this ,What I want is : I want to keep the value of Name and Sex althought it inserted succesfull

}
?>
</form>
```

**I need:**

During insert data into database,I want to keep the value of form like Name,Sex values.So how would I fix this.Anyone help me please,Thanks.

Comment: Step 1: Move your PHP that handles the form submission into its own file. Step 2: Use jQuery to submit the form via AJAX to your PHP controller.

Comment: Where does jQuery fit in to this?  Have you tried just echoing the values with PHP?

Comment: You may want your radio inputs to have the same name but different values (forces only one to be checked), unless you want someone to be able to select both.

Answer (score 0):

submit button clear the forms.
you may use ajax, or jQuery then use ajaxsubmit function, or json. There's a lot of choices.

Comment: Can you help me to find it,I have tried to find it for many time but dose not see what I want.

Answer (score 0):

if html5 local stoage as well as ajax is to complicated for you, you may just set the value of the input field to the post data itself, e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="theName" id="theId" value="<?= $_POST['theName'] ?>" />
```

this way, the input will be displayed after you've submitted the button.

p.s. this is not best practice! if you want to get your code clean you might as well stick with ajax/jquery or html5 local storage, if you are unfamiliar with either of those technologies and you just need to get the value in the form after submitting it, use this "solution"

Comment: This should work. Just make sure, php short tags are turned on. If not then instead of <?= use <?php echo

Comment: as of the release of php 5.4 the "<?=" syntax is always enabled, regardless of php short tags feature being enabled or not. - just for your information : )